# how to uninstall ubuntu 14.04 from a vm already having ubuntu server 16.04 OS

Tags: 14.04

I have ubuntu server 16.04 and ubuntu 14.04 OS installed in my vm.How to remove only 14.04 OS and retain ubuntu 16.04 server OS?

Comment: Come again, who have what where and how? Please look at your issue and see if you can improve the question, don't understand what your asking.

Comment: You have installed __both Ubuntu OS and Ubuntu Server__ in a VM and want to remove __Ubuntu Server__?

Comment: Will you edit your question and show the output of: `sudo lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,fstype;sudo parted -l`?

Comment: @George i want to remove ubuntu os 14.04 and keep ubuntu server image 16.04

Comment: Just remove it from the Virtualbox `machine menu` or `right click` and choose delete all files.

Comment: @george i have a problem..i can only access the terminal of the ubuntu 14.04 OS..not the GUI of ubuntu 14.04 OS

Comment: Are they both not in the Virtualbox machine? You don't need a terminal to remove it unless i am not getting you !

Comment: Let me put up an answer and see if that is what your trying to do .

Comment: See if the answer I put up helps as I can't get what it is you really saying hope it does.

Comment: What's the output of `sudo os-prober`?

Answer (score 1):

To remove a Ubuntu 14.04 from virtualbox:

1. Launch the Virtualbox application

   [image]
2. Select the Ubuntu OS in virtualbox and do two things to remove it:

   a. Right click and select remove

   [image]

   b. Select `machine` from virtualbox menu and select `remove`:

   [image]
3. Delete all files to remove it completely:

   [image]

I hope this is what you are looking for.